# What is the word for the row at the top of this Excel file?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

I am looking for the word for the row at the top of this Excel file that shows what category each cell in the column is in.

[image]

I've been using "header", but I wanted to check if there was a better word for it.

**Example:**

> Does your Excel file have a __ ?

Comment: This is not an English question. It's an Excel question.

Comment: Try sorting your spreadsheet and see what Excel asks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a **header row**.

> Header rows are rows that contain information that help identify the content of a particular column. If the table spans several pages of a print layout, the header row will usually repeat itself at the beginning of each new page.

([Source](http://www.webworks.com/Documentation/Reverb/index.html#page/03.Preparing%20and%20Publishing%20Content/Preparing%20Word%20Files.2.17.htm)) It talks about Word, but it is the same in Excel.

Comment: Check out: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-Excel-table-headers-on-or-off-c91d1742-312c-4480-820f-cf4b534c8b3b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1